# Have an Association Column equal the field of another Column

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, calculated-column

I have created an association column as part of a reusable workflow in SharePoint designer. I am now trying to have this column equal the field of another column in Document Library.

I have tried setting the default to calculated field and then using this script:

=[Location]

However SharePoint is not recognizing this.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or how I can make this possible?

Answer (score 1):

> "However SharePoint is not recognizing this."

What does that mean, exactly?

Are the two fields in the same list? If so then you shouldn't have them in a default value (which is only used when the item is created) and instead have them in a calculated column.

Comment: I essentially need an association column from a sharepoint resuable workflow to equal the same value that appears in a sharepoint list.